# Configurar site no IIS 7. Não starta o site

Tags: asp.net, iis

Criei um site chamado TestePDF. Dei esse alias para ele: testepdf. Criei um diretório e definir como dir virtual(C:\wwwroot\TestePDF). No pool de aplicativos troquei para classico e a versão do .NET de 2.0 para 4.0, apesar de usar o 4.5, mas era a única opção que havia. Quando eu chamo na URL testepdf/, dá o serro de:

> Esta página da web não está disponível(chrome)

**No Conectar como**, eu fiz o seguinte: **Usuário de aplicativo(autenticação de passagem)**
Mesmo assim o site não funciona. Como eu faço para funcionar.

Segui os seguintes tutoriais:

> https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc772350(v=ws.10).aspx
>
> https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/323972
>
> https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/2468142

Pelos tutoriais acima, não consegui fazer funcionar.

No meu editor de configurações está assim:(Não aparece os ícones padrões)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xA4o8.png - Habilite o rastreio e verifique o que acontece;

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30722/discussion-between-dorathoto-and-pnet).

Answer (score 0):

1 - Você não pode ter duas páginas ativas ao mesmo tempo na mesma porta. 
2 - A página que ele lê como padrão é index.html, então criar um site sem isso não vai funcionar, ou  seja, mude o nome do seu index.
3 - Se você colocou a pasta no inetpub e deu certo, provavelmente era algum erro de permissão no IIS para acesso à pasta. Como é uma página de teste faça  o seguinte: no gerenciador do seu site, na lateral direita em Ações, encontre a opção Configurações Básicas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na tela que irá abrir clique em "Testar Configurações". Se o problema for permissão de pasta irá aparecer um alerta em Autorização. Nesse caso você tem duas opções: alterar a permissão da pasta para que o usuário do IIS tenha acesso ou definir que a conexão será feita utilizando seu usuário. Caso deseje a segunda opção, basta voltar na tela anterior e selecionar "Conectar como".